# Generate line graph for any benchmark?

Tags: performance, dataset, graph, benchmarking

I had spent so many hours failing to find a line graph generator for my benchmark results that I just wanted to plug in. I tried quite a few like Google's chart API but it still seemed confusing or not graceful looking, I am clueless.

Examples of benchmark images I wished to make something like are this:
[image]

What specific applications /web services do you recommend for generating something even close to this? I want something "neat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [python mathplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html), which generates beautiful graphs like:
[image: example graph]

[(Source code)](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/plotfile_demo.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). It is not a lib, but a separate executable file. You can output plotting data to one file, and plotting commands in another - script file, which refer to data file. Then call gnuplot with this script file.
Another way is to use [qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/). It is a real library, but it depends on [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). If you already use Qt in your project, it is very straigth way to plot graphs. If not, then just use gnuplot