# Graph better than Google charts?

Tags: php, c++, graph, benchmarking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate line graph for any benchmark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796634/generate-line-graph-for-any-benchmark)

What services do you recommend to generate graphs for benchmark results, like the following?
http://developer.studivz.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/splminheap_rw_mixed.png

Some of the web services I had used were dodgy at best to make these graphs.

Comment: Please don't double post questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Charts is the nicest, I've seen. I mean c'mon, how easy is `<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&chd=t:40,60,60,45,47,75,70,72">`

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&chd=t:40,60,60,45,47,75,70,72

Comment: Finally got the hang of one graph generator that I could mend to my needs, looks nice. Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell if this is sarcasm or not.